# Finding a value of theta where area is minimized (Mostly stuck on the algebra)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> > Question: A goat is tethered with a rope of length R, to a point P, due west of the end of a fence, which runs due north. The region of grass the goat can reach is shown in Figure 3.
> >
> > The following equation gives the area the goat can reach, $A$, as a function of the angle $θ$ shown where $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $
> >
> > $$A(\theta)= \frac{2\pi-\theta}{2}R^2+\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2(1-\cos(\theta))^2+\frac{1}{2}R^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)  $$
> >
> > Find the value of $θ$ where $A(θ)$ is minimised.
> >
> > Here is an image of the question: [image]

My working:

Simplifying first

$$A(\theta)= \frac{2\pi-\theta}{2}R^2+\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2(1-\cos(\theta))^2+\frac{1}{2}R^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)  $$

$$A(\theta)= (\frac{2\pi-\theta}{2})R^2+\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2(1-\cos(\theta))^2+\frac{1}{2}R^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) $$

$$A(\theta)= (\pi -\frac{\theta}{2})R^2+\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2(1-2\cos(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))+\frac{1}{4}R^2 \sin(2\theta) $$

$$A(\theta)= \pi R^2 -\frac{R^2\theta}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2-\frac{1}{2}\pi R^2 \cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{4}\pi R^2\cos^2(\theta)+\frac{1}{4}R^2 \sin(2\theta) $$

Taking the derivative now:

$$ A'(\theta) = \frac{-R^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\pi R^2 \sin(\theta) + \frac{1}{4}\pi R^2(-2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}R^2\cos(2\theta) $$

For min/max $A'(\theta) = 0$

$$  \frac{-R^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\pi R^2 \sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{2}\pi R^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}R^2\cos(2\theta) = 0$$

$$\frac{-R^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\pi R^2 \sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{2}\pi R^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + \frac{1}{2}R^2\cos(2\theta) = 0 $$

$$ \frac{R^2}{2}(-1+ \pi\sin(\theta) -\pi\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + \cos(2\theta) = 0 $$

$$  -1+ \pi\sin(\theta) -\pi\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + 1-2\sin^2(\theta) = 0 $$

$$ 2\sin^2(\theta) - \pi\sin(\theta) + \pi\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) = 0 $$

$$ (\sin(\theta))(2\sin(\theta) - \pi + \pi\cos(\theta)) = 0  $$

$$ \sin(\theta) = 0 $$

$$  2\sin(\theta) - \pi + \pi\cos(\theta) = 0 $$

Now I am stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to go through a lot of calculation.  Note that $$A(\theta) = \frac{R^2}{4}\left(4\pi - 2\theta + \pi (1-\cos\theta)^2 + \sin 2\theta\right).$$  Then, ignoring the constant factor $R^2/4$, $A$ is minimized for some $\theta$ satisfying $$0 = \frac{dA}{d\theta} \propto -2 + \pi (1-\cos\theta)\sin \theta + 2 \cos 2\theta,$$ or equivalently $$1 - \cos 2\theta = \pi(1-\cos \theta)\sin \theta.$$  But note $$1 - \cos 2\theta = 1 - (1 - 2\sin^2 \theta) = 2 \sin^2 \theta,$$ so if $\theta \ne 0$, we get $$2 \sin \theta = \pi (1-\cos\theta),$$ or $$\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos\theta} = \frac{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}}{2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} = \cot \frac{\theta}{2}.$$  It follows that $$\theta = 2 \cot^{-1} \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 1.13382 \approx 64.9633^\circ,$$ wihch is the unique critical point in the interval $0 < \theta < \pi/2$.  Note that the boundary points $\theta \in \{0, \pi/2\}$ also correspond to extrema, but these are maxima.

---

A somewhat different way to go about the solution is to reason that the area $A(\theta)$ is minimized for an angle $\theta$ at which a differential change in the position of the fence is such that the change in the area of the quarter circle to its east is equal in magnitude (but opposite in sign) to the change in area of the strip-like portion of the circle immediately to the west of the fence.  If $0 < x < R$ is the perpendicular distance from the stake to the fence, then a change of $dx$ in $x$ will result in a change of magnitude $\pi (R-x)/2 \, dx$ in the quarter circle, and a change of magnitude $\sqrt{R^2-x^2} \, dx$ in the strip of fence to the west.  Setting these equal, and solving for nontrivial $x$, we get $$x = \frac{\pi^2 - 4}{\pi^2 + 4} R.$$  But $x = R \cos \theta$, hence $$\theta = \cos^{-1} \frac{\pi^2-4}{\pi^2 + 4}.$$  It is a relatively simple exercise to show this is equal to the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following technique will join a $\sin$ term an a $\cos$ term together that have the same period. This is the more general version of what you are looking at.

Consider: $A\sin x+B\cos x = R \sin(x+\alpha)$

Recall that: $R\sin(x+\alpha)=R\sin x\cos \alpha+R\cos x\sin \alpha$

We want $R\cos \alpha = A$ and $R\sin \alpha = B$
Squaring and adding gives: $R^2=A^2+B^2$ hence $R=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$
Dividing gives: $\tan\alpha=\frac{B}{A}$ hence $\alpha=\arctan\frac{B}{A}$

Applying this to your problem gives:

$$  2\sin(\theta) - \pi + \pi\cos(\theta) = 0 $$

$$\sqrt{4+\pi^2}\sin\left(\theta+\arctan\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\pi$$

$$\sin\left(\theta+\arctan\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}$$

$$\theta+\arctan\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}\right)$$

$$(\text{if you take the first quadrant solution it leads to }\theta=0)$$

$$\theta=\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}}\right)-\arctan\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\theta=\pi-2\arctan\frac{\pi}{2}$$

(As we can rewrite the $\arcsin$ as an $\arctan$)

Comment: Ian, you need to clean the arctan

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your last equation $$2\sin(\theta) - \pi + \pi\cos(\theta) = 0$$ $$2\sin(\theta)= \pi(1 - \cos(\theta))$$ $$4\sin^2(\theta)= \pi^2(1 - \cos(\theta))^2$$ $$4-4\cos^2(\theta)=\pi^2-2\pi^2\cos(\theta)+\pi^2\cos^2(\theta)$$ Set $x=\cos(\theta)$ ans solve the quadratic in $x$. You will find two roots $x=1$ and $x=\frac{\pi ^2-4}{\pi ^2+4}$.

So, $$\theta=\cos^{-1}\Big(\frac{\pi ^2-4}{\pi ^2+4}\Big)$$